# for loop with click eventListener only returning last item in array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm *very* new to Coffeescript so I feel like I'm doing something horribly wrong here..

```
paletteItem = document.querySelectorAll('.paletteItem')
```

this creates as an array of divs that I've made– like such: `[div.paletteItem, div.paletteItem, div.paletteItem, etc]`

then when I try to detect a click on an individual one of those divs I do this:

```
paletteItemClickListener = (e) ->
    console.log("clicked on "+ e.innerHTML)

for item in paletteItem
  item.addEventListener("click", () ->
    console.log(item)
    paletteItemClickListener(item)
  )
```

Every time I click the `console.log(item)` is logging as only the *last* item in the array.. not sure why! Am I doing something wrong with my Coffeescript?

Comment: I kind of get what they're trying to say there, but I don't understand how to do it in coffeescript :/

Comment: I think that's a better duplicate given that this is CoffeeScript. Execute summary: use `for item in paletteItem\n do(item) -> ...` instead of `for item in paletteItem\n...` (sorry about the `\n` newlines, formatting is hard in comments).

Comment: yes, thank you that answer was a lot more helpful! it works now :)

Comment: Cool. CoffeeScript has `do` specifically for this case so I figured a CoffeeScript-specific duplicate would be more helpful. Cheers.